# Electric current in a circuit with two batteries

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

I have the following circuit

[image]

in wich both batteries provide the **same** voltage and the capacitors are uncharged.

I need to find the current in each path of the circuit at time $t=0$ when i connect the batteries.

I know that at $t=0$ the charge of the capacitors is zero, so $V_c=\frac qC=0$, and when i apply the laws of Kirchhnoff over the circuit i can ingore them.

Then my circuit is

[image]

But... what's next?

Can i make an equivalent resistance? Because, i can't think of any.

If i want to continue with Kirchhnoff... In what direction does the current flow? And how does the potencial decrease/grows while passing throw each resistance?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, rememebr that homework-like questions are not welcomed here, unless they ask about a conceptual issue, and they must show some effort. Please, consider rewriting your question to fit these requirements. Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Indeed, you must do this using Kirchhoff's laws.

The direction of the current is something that you can CHOOSE. Do not worry: if the current was flowing in the opposite direction, you'll get a minus sign when you solve it.

In other words, now you have to **decide** the reference direction for the currents, just like you choose where you put your origin of coordinates.

Just draw how currents could flow. Suppose that that is the way they flow. Then solve the circuit.

If your assumption was wrong, you will get a minus sign somewhere. That just means that you guessed wrong, but it does not matter, because the numerical value is correct. Only the sign can vary. The sign is telling you if the flow was in that direction or opposite.

---

Actually, what we are doing is a choice of references. "I set that currents will be positive rightwards, and negative leftwards". But this is only a reference. The currents will be unknown until you solve the whole system.